# Запуск скрипта при закрытии попапа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет !
Есть страница с iframe на ней (по кнопке открывается попап с айфреймом, но на весь экран):

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="product-plan">
      <iframe class="product-plan-frame" width="100%" height="100%" src="<?= $arResult["PROPERTIES"]["LINK_MAP"]["VALUE"] ?>"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="hide">
  <div class="box-modal" id="village">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-close_btn arcticmodal-close">
          <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
                d="M8.82125 7.4958L14.7163 1.6008C15.0825 1.23486 15.0825 0.641113 14.7163 0.275176C14.35 -0.0910742 13.7569 -0.0910742 13.3906 0.275176L7.49563 6.17018L1.60031 0.275176C1.23406 -0.0910742 0.640938 -0.0910742 0.274687 0.275176C-0.0915625 0.641113 -0.0915625 1.23486 0.274687 1.6008L6.17 7.4958L0.274687 13.3908C-0.0915625 13.7567 -0.0915625 14.3505 0.274687 14.7164C0.457812 14.8992 0.697812 14.9908 0.9375 14.9908C1.17719 14.9908 1.41719 14.8992 1.60031 14.7161L7.49563 8.82111L13.3906 14.7161C13.5737 14.8992 13.8137 14.9908 14.0534 14.9908C14.2931 14.9908 14.5331 14.8992 14.7163 14.7161C15.0825 14.3502 15.0825 13.7564 14.7163 13.3905L8.82125 7.4958Z"
                fill="#6DB8FB"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="<?= $arResult["PROPERTIES"]["LINK_MAP"]["VALUE"] ?>"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> http://joxi.ru/zANbl1lC60zakA

Нужно запустить скрипт при закрытии попапа, то есть сейчас есть такой код:

```
$(genplan).on('mouseover',  function() {ig_OnOver();}); // запуск скрипта при наведении мыши на фрейм
$(genplan).on('mouseout',   function() {ig_OnOut();}); // запуск скрипта когда убрали мышь с фрейма
$('.open-village').on('click',  function() {ig_OnOver();}); // запуск скрипт при открытии попапа
??????????? // запуск скрипта при закрытии попапа
```

В JS новичок, буду рад любой помощи.
Спасибо !

Comment: Добавьте Вашу разметку `html`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос